# How to make AWS CLI describe-spot-price-history show only what I limit with start and end time options?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I use the start time and end time examples from the output of:

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history help
```

The problem I experience is that I get also some results that are not within the time boundaries I set.
The environment and AWS CLI I use is:

```
ws-cli/2.7.2 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 exe/x86_64.debian.11 prompt/off
```

My command that follows the examples is:

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --availability-zone eu-central-1b --instance-types p3.8xlarge p3.16xlarge --start-time 2023-12-26T09:00:00 --end-time 2023-12-26T10:00:00
```

Aside from what I expect to get within the time bounds set I get records like:

```
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1b",
        "InstanceType": "p3.16xlarge",
        "ProductDescription": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux",
        "SpotPrice": "4.569300",
        "Timestamp": "2023-12-26T05:01:40+00:00"
    },
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1b",
        "InstanceType": "p3.16xlarge",
        "ProductDescription": "SUSE Linux",
        "SpotPrice": "4.539300",
        "Timestamp": "2023-12-26T05:01:40+00:00"
    }
```

and even I do get some records from 2023-12-25.

The examples in the help show only perfect time interval match yet it is not what happens to me.
What am I doing wrong? How to limit the output only to the time bounds set by the respective options?

Comment: I have understood why I get more than one price change record that is before start time I specify. It is because I do not filter by product description which is clearly visible in the sample output I put into the question. Actually it is always only one price change event record per instance type per product specification that is before the start time I set. (Just like John mentions in his answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [describe-spot-price-history — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-spot-price-history.html) says:

> When you specify a start and end time, the operation returns the prices of the instance types within that time range. It **also returns the last price change before the start time**, which is the effective price as of the start time.

It would appear that it is returning details of **whenever the spot price changes** rather than what it is at each second or minute.

Also, it is likely that the price you received for the **previous day** related to the 'last price change before the start time'.